# Python - Splitting a line and extracting characters from the words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading lines from an input file and splitting it into words so I can process each word. I want to get characters from each word at specific indexes. This is what I am trying, which does not work properly, anything greater than word[0] is out of index. I do not understand why it wouldn't work since word should be a string and indexing with strings work without a problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

edit: sorry, to clarify - I want to get characters from word with indexing. e.g word = something, word[3] = 'e'. I am using fileinput module so

```
 import fileinput

 line = f.readline()
 for word in line.split():
     print(word, end="")
     r = int(word[1]) // I want to get the 2nd character from this word in the line
     c = int(word[3])
```

Input File:

```
 1 (1,1)
 2 (1,2) (1,3)
 5 (2,1) (2,2) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3)
 4 (2,3) (2,4) (1,4) (1,5)
 3 (3,4) (3,5) (2,5)
```

I want to set r = the first number in the perenthesis and c = the second number in the parenthesis

Comment: data, the def of `line` is needed for others to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to be a little more careful about filtering out the parentheses and commas. You could use something like this, which should be pretty robust:

```
line = "(1,1) (1,7)\n"
for tup in line.split():
    print(tup)
    # drop parentheses and split at the comma
    vals = tup[1:-1].split(',')
    r = int(vals[0])
    c = int(vals[1])
    print(r)
    print(c)
```

Result:

```
(1,1)
1
1
(1,7)
1
7
```

But actually, your code should work fine too if all the values are single digits:

```
line = "(1,1) (1,7)\n"
for word in line.split():
    print(word)
    r = int(word[1])
    c = int(word[3])
    print(r)
    print(c)

# gives same result
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow you but let me try. Split takes two parameters a separator and a max number of splits. You are telling python to do just one and then selecting the second part of the resulting array. Maybe try something along the lines of:

```
for word in line.split(''):
   print(word, end="")
   # you should check the length of the word
   r = int(word[1]) 
   c = int(word[3])
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('data.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        _, *rest = line.strip().split()

        for x, y in map(literal_eval, rest):
            print((x, y))
            print(x)
            print(y)
```

Which converts the string tuples read from the file into integer tuples with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and prints them out:

```
(1, 1)
1
1
(1, 2)
1
2
(1, 3)
1
3
...
```